# In C++ Explain how compiler able to identify a class is abstract or not ?

Tags: c++, abstract

How Internally compiler identifies wheather class is an abstract (for which we cannot create object)?

Comment: if there is atleast one pure virtual function in a class, then we can say that it is abstract.  Please explain me how compiler is identifying this.

Comment: "*Please explain me how compiler is identifying this.*" The same way the compiler identifies that a class definition is a class definition: by following the C++ grammar. I don't understand the question beyond that. The compiler compiles C++, and C++ defines what a pure virtual function declaration looks like.

Comment: I guess the only real answer to this is "it depends on the compiler". The standard doesn't dictate how the compiler does this.

Comment: ok. Thankyou all for the response

Comment: @SureshNamala - You ought to accept one of the answers. Three of them are correct. Pick one and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is smart enough to check for a pure virtual function in a class or any of the classes it derives from.

If the class itself defines a pure virtual function<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>, it is flagged as Abstract class irrespective of whether it defines the function body.

If a class inherits from a class with pure virtual function then it **must** provide a definition for the pure virtual function.If not it is flagged as Abstract.

<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>

```
virtual void doSomething() = 0;
                          ^^^^^
```

P.S: Yes pure virtual functions can have a definition.

Answer (score 1):

An abstract class will contain at least one pure virtual function. Something like this

```
virtual void foo() = 0;
```

Any classes that derive from this and do not override this such a function will also be abstract

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting the definition and seeing if it is within the definition of an abstract class, of course. How else would this happen?

Comment: "How else would this happen?" The C++ definition of "abstract" class is specific to C++ and is hidden deep in the standard. Certainly the C++ way is not the only way. An `abstract` keyword, for example. Specific to C++, a test for the existence of at least one public constructor would be nice. You cannot create an instance of a class that doesn't have at least one public constructor. That's an abstract class in my eyes, but not in the eyes of the C++.

Comment: @DavidHammen: When you're asking a question about C++, the C++ way *is the only way*. Because the other ways are by definition *not C++*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I do understand the C++ definition. It's just a pet peeve, particularly since `is_default_constructible` doesn't quite work in C++98/03. Compound this with C++11 being off-limits for the foreseeable future ...

Answer (score 0):

Class is abstract if at least one of its members is abstract. So, if class contains at least one pure virtual function, it is abstract from compiler point of view.

```
virtual void PureVirtualMethod() = 0;   // Any class that has methods
                                        // with such declaration is abstract.
```